# Particle System interact with objects

Tags: modeling, particles, system

I'm currently working on a carved wooden heart lying in a field of grass using the grass essentials you can grab from Blender Guru and as you can see there is some clipping that occurs. I know how to make sure grass wont appear from under the wooden heart, that is not the issue. What I want to do is make it so that the grass around the edge of the heart is slightly bent, that you can actively see the grass is being pushed aside by the object. Is there a way to do this in the particle system? The only thing I can think of short term is to apply the particle system and just do it manually, but with so many vertices that would be an absolute pain to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.[image: Wooden heart in open field]

Answer (score 1):

The [Particle Edit Mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/mode.html) could be quiet handy for this. The settings can be found in the left menu (shortcut **T**). Also there is the option to just edit the tips (see bottom toolbar).

For "real" interaction you probably need to use *Hair dynamics* and add a *Collision* component to the heart